# Read each line and use the line as input

Tags: linux, bash

What I want to achieve is:

1.Read a file line by line.
    2.Put each content in a variable (stopping at the EOF, problem here is I don't know how many lines there is)
        3.Use the variables separate in another file.

example file:

1. 123
2. 345
3. 567
4. etc (max 10 lines)

output file

1. this is 123
2. this is 345
3. this is 567

Is this possible?

```
> while IFS=$'\n' read -r v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7; do
>         # put each new line a var
>         echo "this is $v1" >>log.txt
>         echo "this is $v2" >>log.txt
>         etc.. ;
> 
> done
```

Comment: +1 for research effort :-) One question, though: do you need to access the lines of the input in random order? Because in your example, you use the lines sequentially.

Comment: yes, I need to access the lines in sequence.

Comment: Then it seems a simple `while read line; do echo "this is $line" >>log.txt; done` might do, unless I misunderstood. `read` will assign each entire input line to `$line` in turn. But if you want to access the lines in random order, then you do need Glenn's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mapfile` command would be useful here: it reads a file into an array, each line being an array element:

```
mapfile -t lines < filename
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    echo "this is $line"
done
```

ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile